# JavaScript Craps game using two arrays to generate the "point"

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are no errors on plnkr.co, yet the div button still doesn't work.

1) Am I on the right track for pulling two random numbers from two arrays, adding them and returning the result when the button is clicked.
2) I saw the undefined error when I ran the code on here, but I am not sure what to troubleshoot. The code didn't give any errors on plnkr.co.

```js
//button event will generate 2 random numbers and add them together

var num1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var num2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
//var sum1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
//var sum2 = num1 + num2

function rollDice(){
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(num1 + num2));
 document.getElementById("roll").innerHTML = randomNumber[rollDice];
 }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: darkred;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
   color: white;
   font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>JavaScript Craps using arrays</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="random.css">
 <script src="craps.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<h1> Craps Lounge</h1>

<div id="button">
<button onclick="randomNumber()">Roll the Bones</button>
</div>

<p id="roll"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with your code:

- you need to actually call rollDice() function.
- you can't find randomNumber like that, you need two random index to select two numbers from the two arrays you have defined. you can use `Math.random()` for this, like in the code below:
- `randomNumber[rollDice]` is wrong since randomNumber is a number and not an object.

```js
//button event will generate 2 random numbers and add them together

var num1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var num2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
//var sum1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
//var sum2 = num1 + num2

function rollDice(){
    var randomIndex1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*num1.length);
    var randomIndex2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*num2.length);
 var randomNumber = num1[randomIndex1] + num2[randomIndex2];
 document.getElementById("roll").innerHTML = randomNumber;
 }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: darkred;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
   color: white;
   font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>JavaScript Craps using arrays</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="random.css">
 <script src="craps.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<h1> Craps Lounge</h1>

<div id="button">
<button onclick="rollDice()">Roll the Bones</button>
</div>

<p id="roll"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Previous code:
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(num1 + num2));

I was attempting to construct a variable that would round down a randomly generated number. My presumption was that the function would add and index two separate arrays then add them.

Comment: New code:
var randomIndex1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*num1.length);
var randomIndex2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*num2.length);
var randomNumber = num1[randomIndex1] + num2[randomIndex2];

Indexes each array seperately within the same function and using the length property to reference the number of items in the arrays. Another variable was created to add these two results together.

Comment: Previous HTML
<button onclick="randomNumber()">Roll the Bones</button>

New HTML
<button onclick="rollDice()">Roll the Bones</button>

Previous HTML was calling a variable. New HTML is calling a function(object).

Thank you very much for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

I seen a few things. I refactored to what I believe you was trying to achieve.

```js
//button event will generate 2 random numbers and add them together

var num1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var num2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
//var sum1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
//var sum2 = num1 + num2

function rollDice() {
  
  //random # between 1 and 6
  var dice1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * num1.length) + 1);
  var dice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * num2.length) + 1);
  
  var randomNumber = dice1 + dice2;
  document.getElementById("roll").innerHTML = randomNumber;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: darkred;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
   color: white;
   font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>JavaScript Craps using arrays</title>
 
</head>
<body>
<h1> Craps Lounge</h1>

<div id="button">
<button onclick="rollDice()">Roll the Bones</button>
</div>

<p id="roll"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I implemented the first answer successfully. I see that your statements include +1 and return the same result. Thus is the inclusion of a +1 extraneous?

Comment: I believe it just marks an answer as working. One can take multiple avenues in solving a problem. So there can be more than one correct answer.